# Opening programs very slow on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: performance

When I open any program for first time after boot, it loads VERY slowly (Doesn't matter how long after boot). For example, terminal takes 2-3 seconds, skype and firefox often take much longer. If I close it and open again, it loads in reasonable time (<1 second).
I got Intel Core i5-2500K CPU @ 3.30GHz, so it shouldn't be hardware issue...

What is causing this?

**Disk benchmark**:

> Average read time: 115.5 MB/s (100 samples)
>
> Average write time: 98.7 MB/s (100 samples)
>
> Average access time: 11.79 msec (1000 samples)

Comment: may be you have slow disk

Comment: Disk Utility >Read only benchmark

Comment: Avg read time: 115.5 MB/s (100 samples)
Avg write time: 98.7 MB/s (100 samples)
Avg access time: 11.79 msec (1000 samples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your application to the **Startup Applications** list and see if delay still occurs or not. If so, then it might be a misconfiguration with your preferred hardware and Ubuntu.

Comment: I tested this by killing and restarting X, and apps are instantly loaded!